# #kentico cms to salesforce community login SSO

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on, integration, kentico

We have a website running on Kentico and we want all the users who are coming to kentico and doing login can automatically login to salesforce community after clicking a tab in kentico website . 
I got few suggestions related to SSO but it seems there is no specific way in kentico cms for doing or configuring single sign on for other domains . 
Let me know if you guys have any thoughts . 
Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing much about Salesforce Community, I'll answer based on what we've done in the past in other situations which are similar.

In this case it seems like Salesforce will be your true source of the "user" data because there are license restrictions with users in Salesforce and NOT in Kentico.  Some of the user data (username, first, last, etc.) will be stored in Kentico to help with functionality.  In this case you'd:

1. Place the login webpart on a page and configure it (simple).
2. Create a [Global Event Handler](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/custom-development/handling-global-events) for the [Authenticate](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/custom-development/handling-global-events/reference-global-system-events#Reference-Globalsystemevents-SecurityEvents) event.
3. In the global event handler, attempt to log them into Salesforce with given username and password.
4. If a user exists or the login is successful, allow them to log into Kentico and possibly sync some of their profile/user data to Kentico, if not, cancel the event.

Comment: We have users data in sync on both systems and Users are going to login into kentico website first with their credentials then on certain click of button they should be logged in into salesforce . Basically its a SSO from Kentico to salesforce . 
Identity Provider : Kentico 
Service Provider : Salesforce

Comment: Then follow the steps u outlined above and create a global handler. AFAIK there is no SSO provider for Kentico to connect to Salesforce.